# Disable docker setup in mupx deployment

Tags: meteor, deployment

I am trying to simple meteor application using **mupx**. In my scenario, I want to bypass docker setup and all docker options because everything is already installed on my destination server. 
how can I do that ? I am using mupx 1.5.2 version. 
here is my mup.json file.

```
{
 "servers": [
  {
  "host": "MY_HOSR",
  "username": "USER",
  "password": "PASSWORD",
  "env": {}
  }
],
  "setupMongo": false,
  "setupNode" : false,
  "appName": "blank",
  "app": "/home/rut2/meteor_workspace/blank",
  "env": {
  "PORT": 3000,
  "ROOT_URL": "http://MY_HOST:3000"
},
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

The reason I want to disable this is, I never could deploy successfully with this options. It always gives me error while starting meteor/ verifying deployment stage. (I will discuss error if anyone wants to help on that one also.)

I had the lower version of mup (1.0.1, which is without docker options), and it was working perfectly.

Please help me guys. I have been stuck here since 3 days. tried every issues, every forum I found related.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: I am really new at docker. I don't know how to troubleshoot with this. I belive that its problem with docker image, because my project is simple-todo template. and it can not deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mupx without docker. I had these kind of problems too, some solutions that works for me: upgrade server node version, increase deploy wait time, custom image.

Comment: Hello @perusopersonale, thank you for your answer. I have tried first and second options already. It's not working. I also tried to change docker image by {dockerImage : "other/image"} in mup.json file. not but not working. can you help me with how to change docker image ?